# How can I properly quote bash commands in python when using `subprocess.check_output`?

Tags: python, bash, shell, time, subprocess

I'm trying to run and read the output of `time` command in python. The problem is that `time` command works differently in `/bin/sh` and `/bin/bash` like so:

```
sh $ time ls
..
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 3856maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+305minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

and the `/bin/bash` version is:

```
bash $ time ls
..

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

I need the latter one as it's more precise than the former.

Hence I'm trying to wrap the command with `bash -c '<command>'` in `check_output` but it gives me an error as such:

```
>>> s.check_output(["bash", "-c", "'time ls'"])                                  
bash: time ls: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 544, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['bash', '-c', "'time ls'"]' returned non-zero exit status 127
```

When I exclude the extra quote, output does not capture timing information:

```
>>> s.check_output(['bash', '-c', 'time ls'])

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
'..'
```

And lastly when I use `executable` parameter instead of wrapping, output does not capture anything:

```
>>> s.check_output(['time', 'ls'], shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `/bin/sh`, `time ls` runs the external program `/usr/bin/time` (your path may vary), which then runs `ls` and reports the timing information to its standard error.

With `/bin/bash`, `time` is a keyword which instructs the `bash` shell itself to report timing information for the execution of `ls` to standard error. As such, you need to redirect the standard error of the shell, not the command, to standard output so that `check_output` can capture it. It's a little ugly, but

```
s.check_output('exec 2>&1; time ls >/dev/null 2>&1', executable='/bin/bash', shell=True)
```

should work. The `exec 2>&1` is the part that lets `check_output` capture anything. The redirections following `ls` are there to remove the output of `ls` from what is captured; you can delete them if you want the command output as well.

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused by the fact that you should **not** quote strings when proving a list as command line. In fact:

```
>>> s.check_output(['bash', '-c', "time ls"])

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
'some content produced by ls'
```

Doesn't raise any exception, while:

```
>>> s.check_output(['bash', '-c', "'time ls'"])
bash: time ls: comando non trovato
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/subprocess.py", line 586, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['bash', '-c', "'time ls'"]' returned non-zero exit status 127
```

Raises the exception you see. Note the line before the traceback:

```
bash: time ls: comando non trovato
```

Quoting the `'time ls'` made `bash` search for the program `time ls` instead of program `time` to be run with `ls` as argument.

Why quoting is not needed? Easy: the list of strings specifies how the command line should be splitted. Putting `"time ls"` in a single element of the list already provides the "quoting" you want.

---

As to how to obtain the output you want, since `bash`'s `time` outputs on `stderr`, a solution is to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` (and remove `ls` output).

```
>>> s.check_output(['bash', '-c', "time ls > /dev/null"], stderr=s.STDOUT)
'\nreal\t0m0.001s\nuser\t0m0.000s\nsys\t0m0.000s\n'
```