# Python, subprocess.check_call() and pipes redirection

Tags: python, shell

Why am I getting list of files when executing this command?

```
subprocess.check_call("time ls &>/dev/null", shell=True)
```

If I will paste

```
time ls &>/dev/null
```

into the console, I will just get the timings.
OS is Linux Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21003633/1189040) ?

Comment: Why are you using `shell=True` in the first place here?

Comment: Himal - adding "executable='/bin/bash'" fixed my problems, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

On debian-like systems, the default shell is `dash`, not `bash`.  `Dash` does not support the `&>` shortcut.  To get only the subprocess return code, try:

```
subprocess.check_call("time ls >/dev/null 2>&1", shell=True)
```

To get subprocess return code and the timing information but not the directory listing, use:

```
subprocess.check_call("time ls >/dev/null", shell=True)
```

Minus, of course, the subprocess return code, this is the same behavior that you would see on the `dash` command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

The Python version is running under `sh`, but the console version is running in whatever your default shell is, which is probably either `bash` or `dash`. (Your `sh` may actually be a different shell running in POSIX-compliant mode, but that doesn't make any difference.)

Both `bash` and `dash` have builtin `time` functions, but `sh` doesn't, so you get `/usr/bin/time`, which is a normal program. The most important difference this makes is that the `time` builtin is not running as a subprocess with its own independent stdout and stderr.

Also, `sh`, `bash`, and `dash` all have different redirection syntax.

---

But what you're trying to do seems wrong in the first place, and you're just getting lucky on the console because two mistakes are canceling out.

You want to get rid of the stdout of `ls` but keep the stderr of `time`, but that's not what you asked for. You're trying to redirect both stdout and stderr: that's what `>&` means on any shell that actually supports it.

So why are you still getting the `time` stderr? Either (a) your default shell doesn't support `>&`, or (b) you're using the builtin instead of the program, and you're not redirecting the stderr of the shell itself, or maybe (c) both of the above.

---

If you really want to do exactly the same thing in Python, with the exact same bugs canceling out in the exact same way, you can run your default shell manually instead of using `shell=True`. Depending on which reason it was working, that would be either this:

```
subprocess.check_call([os.environ['SHELL'], '-c', 'time ls &> /dev/null'])
```

or this:

```
subprocess.check_call('{} -c time ls &> /dev/null'.format(os.environ(SHELL), shell=True)
```

---

But really, why are you doing this at all? If you want to redirect stdout and not stderr, write that:

```
subprocess.check_call('time ls > /dev/null', shell=True)
```

Or, better yet, why are you even using the shell in the first place?

```
subprocess.check_call(['time', 'ls'], stdout=subprocess.devnull)
```

Comment: ls was just an example, I'm timing an application with produces loads of output both on stdout and stderr, sometimes I want to see the stderr, but usually not. Obviously I would like to see the timing, which is what's happening right now. Basically my command looks something like "time taskset mpirun ./app", and I would like to discard output from ./app (taskset and mpirun are pretty silent anyway). Anyway, thanks for making me realize that time is not in sh, I will try your solutions tomorrow.

Comment: In python 3.7, I had to use `subprocess.DEVNULL` (capitalized)